# Bootstrap Input Group pushes control little to left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to layout a form using bootstrap 3 but for some reason the input is pushed to left.
My markup looks like this

```
<div class="jumbotron">

<form name="invoiceForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-toggle="validator">


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="txt_job_date"  >Date work performed</label>
        <p class="input-group col-sm-3">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
                   is-open="opened" min-date="minDate"
                   max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                   date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                   ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close"
                   id="txt_job_date"
                   ng-model="job_date"
                    />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="txt_job_ref_no" required-asterix="" >Ref No</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ref_no" id="txt_job_ref_no" placeholder="123RTE" required="">
        </div>
        <div role="alert">
        <span class="error has-error alert-danger" ng-show="invoiceForm.txt_job_ref_no.$error.required">
            Ref no is required!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

[Here is the link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scoobydoo74/j8x15dbs/)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. Wrap the labels and elements in cols, and the form in a `.container` inside the `.jumbotron`. You were over-complicating the layout.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
    <form name="invoiceForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-toggle="validator">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="txt_job_date">Date work performed</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
                       is-open="opened" min-date="minDate"
                       max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                       date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                       ng-required="true"
                       close-text="Close"
                       id="txt_job_date"
                       ng-model="job_date"
                        />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="txt_job_ref_no" required-asterix="" >Ref No</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ref_no" id="txt_job_ref_no" placeholder="123RTE" required="">


        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8x15dbs/1/

---

**Edit: Missed part about form being horizontal. Added new code below to reflect that.**

This has the layout you're looking for

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="txt_job_date">Date work performed</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
                    is-open="opened" min-date="minDate"
                    max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                    date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                    ng-required="true"
                    close-text="Close"
                    id="txt_job_date"
                    ng-model="job_date"
                />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="txt_job_ref_no" required-asterix="">Ref No</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ref_no" id="txt_job_ref_no" placeholder="123RTE" required="required">
    </div>
</div>


</form>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8x15dbs/2/

A real easy thing to do - and a great way to learn - is to just copy the examples off of Bootstrap's site and replace their values with yours. :)

Comment: Thanks @timgavin but I want a form-group layout like label on left and textbox on right.

Comment: Brilliant!! thank you very much.. this approach is very simple.Gotta read the documentation now. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, it can get confusing at first, and it's REAL easy to over complicate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

remove `<col-sm-2>` from before the input tag. As good practice, always use `<div class="row">` before using `<col-sm-12>` and don't use rows or columns inside `<div class="form-group">`

Please read about [bootstrap scaffolding](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) to understand how to write good markup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am reading the documentation now..thanks again